# Triangle Puzzle: Find maximum total from top to bottom, starting at top moving moving to adjacent numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

As the title suggests, I need to solve this puzzle.

```
       5
      9 6
     4 6 8 
    0 7 1 5
```

The path I need to find is the max sum from top to bottom, only moving to adjacent children. So this path would be 5-9-6-7, with a sum of 27.

My code works for every set of data I input myself, but when I attempt the puzzles with the provided textFile's data, my sum/answer is not accepted as correct.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code. Is there some exception I am not seeing?

```
public class Triangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("Tri.txt");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try{
            //Read the file and add all integers into an array with the correct size. Array size is found with number of bytes file.length()
            //Parse string to integer
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            fis.read(bytes);
            fis.close();
            String[] valueStr = new String(bytes).trim().split("\\s+");
            int[] list = new int[valueStr.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < valueStr.length; i++) 
                list[i] = Integer.parseInt(valueStr[i]);

            System.out.println(computeMaxPath(list));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static int computeMaxPath(int[] list){

        //Disregard row number one since it is the root. Start row number count at 2
        int rowNumber = 2;
        //set the sum to the value of the root.
        int sum = list[0];
        //selected index begins at the root, index 0
        int selectedIndex = 0;

        for (int j = 1; j < list.length; j=j+rowNumber)
        {
            // for every iteration the right child is found by adding the current selected index by z. What is z?
            // the left child is of course found in the index -1 of the right child. 
            // z is the amount of of elements in the triangle's row. Row 3 has 3 elements, 4 has 4, etc. 
            // For exmaple, if the selectedIndex is index 4, its right child can be found by adding the index to the next row element count. 
            // 4 + 4 = 8 the right child is in index 8 and left is in index 7
            int rightChildIndex = selectedIndex + rowNumber;
            int leftChildIndex = selectedIndex + rowNumber - 1;

            //set the appropriate index for the greater child's index
            selectedIndex = list[rightChildIndex] >= list[leftChildIndex] ? rightChildIndex : leftChildIndex;

            //increment the sum of the path
            sum = sum + list[selectedIndex];

            System.out.println(selectedIndex);

            //increment the row number
            rowNumber++;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Essentially, my algorithm works by adding the string of ints from the text file into an array. The first selected index is of course the root node. To find the right child I add the selected index by the next row's length and subtract by 1 to find the left child index.

Any ideas?

Comment: *only moving to adjacent children. So this path would be 5-9-6-7*, this makes no sense given the structure you show. You need to explain why these are *adjacent* because they are not obviously adjacent in any intuitive way.

Comment: It makes sense to me... although it is worded strangely.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson could you explain what exactly is hard to understand about this? the explanation might be a bit odd, but perfectly makes sense to me.

Comment: your algorithm is wrong, because on every row it picks current biggest number, but it does not always lead to biggest total path, imagine triangle where all numbers are 1 except bottom-left is 2, your algorithm will go on right side of triangle, but it should analyze all possible combinations of paths and pick longest one

Comment: great it makes sense to you, like I said, there is no obvious adjacency from that path given the triangle example. How do you get from 5 to 9 to 6 to 7 is not obvious. If it was top to bottom, left to right then it would be 5946807. Good luck if you do not want to explain it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson well, the description is using quite a lot of naming conventions, but to anyone who has worked with trees or is willing to understand this it shouldn't be a problem to understand this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This algorithm uses the wrong logic. In this case your algorithm works because it has the required properties to make your algorithm work, for other inputs this obviously not the case. For example consider the following (extreme) example:

```
          1
         1 0
        0 0 9
```

Your algorithm works by simply always selecting the child with the larger sum, so in this case your algorithm would result in the path `{1 , 1 , 0}`, while the correct algorithm would result in `{1 , 0 , 9}`.

The correct algorithm would require to traverse the tree and search **all** paths in order to find the correct solution:

```
int findSum(int[] tree , int at_node){
    if(at_node >= length(tree))
        return 0 //end of the tree, quit recursive search

    //maximum-path including node is the path with the greatest sum that includes either the left or right child of the node.
    return max(findSum(tree , leftChild(at_node)) , 
                  findSum(tree , rightChild(at_node)) + tree[at_node]
}
```

---

As @JohnBollinger mentioned:
This top-to-bottom-approach is pretty simple. But on cost of efficiency. A more efficient, but also more efficient solution that only traverses each node exactly once. In the above stated algorithm a tree that represents the time each node was visited would look like a pascal's triangle, thus making `2 ^ height` array-lookups. The bottom-top approach would only require `height + height - 1 + ... + 1` lookups.

```
int findSumBottomTop(int[] tree , int height){
    //initialize counter for previous level
    int[] sums = new int[height + 1]
    fill(sums , 0)

    //counter for the level counts down to 1 (note that this variable is not 0-based!!!)
    int lvl = height

    //counter for nodes remaining on the current level (0-based)
    int remaining_in_lvl = lvl - 1
    //maximum-paths for each node on the current level
    int[] next_level = new int[lvl]

    //iterate over all nodes of the tree
    for(int node = length(tree) - 1; node > -1 ; node--){
        int left_max_path = sums[remaining_in_lvl]
        int right_max_path = sums[remaining_in_lvl + 1]

        next_level[remaining_in_lvl] = max(right_max_path , left_max_path) + tree[node]

        //decrement counter for remaining nodes
        remaining_in_lvl -= 1

        if(remaining_in_lvl == -1){
            //end of a level was encountered --> continue with lvl = lvl - 1
            lvl--
            //update to match length of next 
            remaining_in_lvl = lvl - 1

            //setup maximum-path counters for next level
            sums = next_level
            next_level = new int[sums.length - 1]
     }

     //there is exactly one sum remaining, which is the sum of the maximum-path
     return sums[0];
 }
```

The basic idea of this would be the following:

```
 Consider this example tree:
     0    ^         6
    0 1   |        3 6
   0 1 2  |       1 3 5
  0 1 2 3 |      0 1 2 3
                0 0 0 0 0
tree   traversal  sums
```

sums would be the values of sums that would be produced for each level. We simply start searching at the bottom and searching the maximum-path from each node in a level to the bottom. This would be the maximum of the maximum-path of the left child and the maximum-path of the right child + the value of the node.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't understanding the question. Thank you.

Comment: A far more efficient solution involves traversing the tree from leaves to root.  At each node you can then compute the sum of the maximum path from the subtree rooted at that node to any leaf, by considering only the results already computed for its own children.  When you process the root, you have the answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thought I'd keep things simple, since OP seems to be new to tree-processing algorithms, but you're right. The bottom-top approach would be more efficient that top-to-bottom-traversal

Comment: @Paul Could you give me an idea how you would implement leftChild() rightChild() for the recursive approach

Comment: @Andy there would be a few approaches. The simplest would be to add a parameter for the level of the node as parameter. Saves you the a lot of calculations and you can use the same approach like in your code. But I can post a rule to find the left and right child in an arithmetic way aswell, if you prefer.

Comment: @Paul yea I dont understand how I would increment the level appropriately

Comment: @Andy each recursive call steps one level down in the tree, so the new method-signature would be `int findSum(int[] tree , int at_node , int level)` and the calls would be refactored to `findSum(tree , leftChild(at_node) , level + 1)` and same for `rightChild(...)` respectively.

Comment: @Paul okay thanks. I understand that method now. Its unrealistic though since I have 100 levels. I'll have to use the more efficient one

Comment: @Andy yeah, for a height of 100 the top-bottom-approach would produce quite a lot of overhead. Though you could optimize that a bit aswell using the same approach as for the bottom-top-approach.

Comment: @Paul well I cant get the findSumBottomTop() to run without out of bounds error. argh, nor am I really understanding it

Comment: @Andy I've already mentioned there might be some issues with the bounds. I'll debug that and post the correct version. And I'm gonna try to explain it a little bit better.

Comment: @Andy I've updated the solution with working code (no OutOfBoundsException) and a hopefully better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

if there is not limit on the number of rows, for example, input can have hundred of rows. it worth to implement this like a [directed acyclic  graph](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/) and then use an [algorithm to find the largest path](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int computeMaxPath(int[] a, int self, int row) {
    if (self >= a.length)
        return 0;
    else
        return a[self] + Math.max(
            computeMaxPath(a, self + row + 1, row + 1),
            computeMaxPath(a, self + row + 2, row + 1));
}

static int computeMaxPath(int[] a) {
    return computeMaxPath(a, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my favorite Project Euler problems (#18). Just for reference, here's a complete bottom-to-top solution in the Haskell language:

```
f = foldr (\a b -> let c = zipWith (+) a b
                   in if null (drop 1 c)
                         then c
                         else zipWith max c (tail c)) (repeat 0)

main = print (f z) where
  z = map (map read . words) (lines s) :: [[Int]]
```